# How to check for a duplicate value before inserting with SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, duplicates

I've created an INSERT SQL query which works fine... Until I try to send a duplicate value. I'm glad the database stops the duplicate values but I don't want the system to crash. I want to know how I can check if the value I want to enter is already in the database. If it is, clear the box and produce a message box. If it isn't, carry on with the INSERT command
Here is my code:

`Dim strPersonID As String = cboPersonID.Text
        If strPersonID = "" Then Exit Sub
        'Declares contents of text boxes as a string so it can be used in the 
        'SQL string
        Dim strForename As String = txtForename.Text
        Dim strSurname As String = txtSurname.Text
        Dim strDateOfBirth As String = txtDateOfBirth.Text
        Dim strCurrentlyWith As String = CheckIfWith()
        Dim strConditions As String = txtConditions.Text
        'Add new record to table
        Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO tblDetail VALUES('" & strPersonID _
             & "','" & strForename & "','" & strSurname & "','" & strDateOfBirth & "'," & strCurrentlyWith & ",'" & strConditions & "')"
        Dim CM As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, CN)`

Comment: there's always `on error resume next` if you don't want it to crash.

Comment: I need the user to enter a value of somekind, unfortunately can't skip it :/

Comment: a) use parameters instead of concatenating strings (not only MUCH safer, the code is easier to read) b) check the DB for existing data doing a SELECT (maybe using COUNT) before you INSERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your insert inside of an If not Exists statement

```
Dim strSQL As String = "If Not Exists (" & _
             "Select * From tblDetail "  & _
             "Where PersonId = " & strPersonID & ")" & _
    "INSERT INTO tblDetail VALUES('" & strPersonID _   
         & "','" & strForename & "','" & strSurname & 
         "','" & strDateOfBirth & "'," &
          strCurrentlyWith & ",'" & strConditions & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Just tried this and it tells me that it's expecting either INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, PROCEDURE or SELECT

Comment: Yes, you need to "Execute" this statement, not run it as straight SQL. If you connecting to the database using OleDB, then I think you need to execute the command using `ExecuteNonQuery`, or something like that, rather than however you are doing it now... Look up the OleDB docs for an example...

Answer (score 0):

You could always catch the exception and then pop up the message based on that.  A more complex alternative would be to start a transaction, run a select query to check for a duplicate, then if there are no duplicates, run your insert statement, and commit the transaction.  If there are duplicates, you could commit the transaction and inform the user.

Here's a rough idea of how you'd do it with a try-catch block:

```
        Try
            'put your code here that could throw the exception.
        Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
            If (ex.Message.Contains("whatever the message is stating you have a duplicate")) Then
                MsgBox("You have a duplicate!")
            End If
        End Try
```

Comment: Sorry, bit of a coding newbie at the mo, how would I go about this Catch?